# Detection of var vulnerability: problem with search string

Tags: vulnerability

SmartCheck tool at:
[SmartChek: Static Analysis of Ethereum Smart Contracts](https://s-tikhomirov.github.io/assets/papers/smartcheck.pdf)
suggests detection of 'var' key word in the smart contract by searching the assignment statement such that the Left Hand Side of assignment statement contains var keyword and Right Hand Side contains the integer value.
 But it says usage of search string: (matches ˆ[0-9]+$). I can’t understand the use of ‘$’ sign in the above search string.

Some body please guide me.

Comment: Your question is off-topic, as it doesn't actually relate to Ethereum. The pattern is a regular expression, and the `$` means the end of the string. The web has a lot of resources for learning about regular expressions. But FYI, the `var` keyword doesn't exist anymore in current versions of Solidity.

Comment: Thanks for clarification of '$'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are referring to section 2.25 *Unsafe type inference*. In that context it means the checker verifies expressions like

```
var XXXX = YYYY
```

It verifies that `YYYY` is an integer constant.